# What's causing an extra heading numbering?

Tags: sectioning, memoir, org-mode

See the TOC in PDF [image: pdf output of TOC]

For the **four stars** sub-heading, LaTeX inserts an extra decimal numbering. It should be 0.1.1.1 instead of 0.1.1.0.1. An extra zero. It persists in subsequent sub-headings. What's causing it? How can I undo it?

I am using orgmode with memoir doc class. It happens only when exporting to PDF and does not happen when exporting to HTML and other formats. I do not have any custom classes or changes to defaults (that I know of).

As requested, I'm including the lengthy .tex file here:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[total={6.00in,9.5in},top=0.75in, left=1.25in, letterpaper, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\raggedright
\raggedbottom
\linespread{1.17}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm} % Default is 15pt.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{block-gray}{gray}{0.90}
\newtcolorbox{myquote}{colback=block-gray,grow to right by=-4mm,grow to left by=-4mm,boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,breakable,parbox=false,enhanced}
\NewEnviron{myblock} {\colorbox{block-gray}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-10\fboxsep\relax}{\small\addtolength{\leftskip}{4mm} \addtolength{\rightskip}{4mm} \BODY}}}
\renewcommand{\quote}{\myblock}
\renewcommand{\endquote}{\endmyblock}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,mindmap,trees,graphs,shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{chronosys}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage{Konanur,lettrine}
\renewcommand\LettrineFontHook{\Konanurfamily}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true}
\newcommand\myshade{85}
\colorlet{mylinkcolor}{violet}
\colorlet{mycitecolor}{YellowOrange}
\colorlet{myurlcolor}{Aquamarine}
\hypersetup{linkcolor = mylinkcolor!\myshade!black}
\hypersetup{citecolor = mycitecolor!\myshade!black}
\hypersetup{urlcolor = myurlcolor!\myshade!black}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}
\hypersetup{
 pdftitle={One star},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 25.1.50.11 (Org mode 8.3.5)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}
\tableofcontents

\section{two stars}
\label{sec:orgheadline6}
\subsection{three stars}
\label{sec:orgheadline5}
\paragraph{four stars}
\label{sec:orgheadline4}
\subparagraph{five stars}
\label{sec:orgheadline3}
\begin{enumerate}
\item six stars
\label{sec:orgheadline2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item seven stars
\label{sec:orgheadline1}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Final Update:

I located the error to missing lines in (setq org-latex-classes) variable as described [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html). And the missing lines are chapter and subsubheading that user touhami and others have pointed out. Those same lines are also missing in some places in the org-mode worg webpage. I am accepting touhami's response provided users follow through on fixing the variable to:

```
 (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
 '("memoir"
 "\\documentclass{memoir}"
 ("\\chapter{%s}"         . "\\chapter*{%s}")
 ("\\section{%s}"         . "\\section*{%s}")
 ("\\subsection{%s}"      . "\\subsection*{%s}")
 ("\\subsubsection{%s}"   . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
 ("\\paragraph{%s}"       . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
 ("\\subparagraph{%s}"    . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

Thanks for locating the problem.

Comment: Are you sure there is not some level omitted? Can you show the `.tex` file please?

Comment: I added the lengthy .tex code above.

Comment: as @ChristianHupfer noticed `\subsubsection` level was be omitted.

Comment: The list of packages is very doubtful, some of them aren't needed any longer and the order is wrong for some of them! Is this what `org-mode` generates?

Comment: Your document is missing both `chapter`-level and `subsubsection`-level dividers. Hence the zeroes at the first and fourth positions of the sectioning headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `memoir` class one can divide a document into 8 levels

> ```
>  1. book ------------------> level -2
>  2. part ------------------> level -1
>  3. chapter ---------------> level 0
>  4. section ---------------> level 1
>  5. subsection ------------> level 2
>  6. subsubsection ---------> level 3
>  7. paragraph -------------> level 4
>  8. subparagraph-----------> level 5
> ```

With the standard classes `book` and `report`, there is no `book` division.
The same holds for the KOMA-script classes `scrbook` and `scrreprt`.

With the standard class `article` and the KOMA-script class `scrartcl`, there are no `book` and `chapter` divisions.

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%\book{Level -2}% only with memoir
\part{level -1}
%\chapter{level 0}% no chapter with article or scrartcl
\section{level 1}
\subsection{level 2}
\subsubsection{level 3}
\paragraph{level 4}
\subparagraph{level 5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where was this omitted? In memoir style file? Where do I put it back? I'm using orgmode in Emacs to generate the .tex and .pdf files.

Comment: @EmacsUser: I am a Emacs user as well, but I don't need such things like an org mode -- you learn nothing by using this.

Comment: @EmacsUser i have no idea with Emacs. Hope that Christian can help you. In  your code `\paragraph{four stars}` should be `\subsubsection{four stars}` `\paragraph`, and  `\subparagraph` come after it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, agree -- but for this collaborative publication, I have to work with memoir and orgmode. Actually I'm enjoying the code support in orgmode so I can have source code, evaluated code, and results of the evaluation in the same file. Saves lots of editing trips.